# Images not getting displayed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, heroku, amazon-s3

I am facing the following problem.

I am not able to see the images (Seen as broken images).

Till yesterday everything was working properly, I did the following and from that on-wards its giving error.
I wanted one image(without using file uploader, eg. carrierwave) from file-system to be changed on the server, So I did the following steps -

Copied the image to local /app/assets/images

Asset complied on local with : bundle exec rake assets:precompile

Image Committed with same name on Git

Image did not reflect on production

So I executed the command to compile on production : bundle exec rake assets:precompile ENV=production

Also executed this command on Heroku bash : heroku run bash --app ashoka-survey-web --account uwashoka

Result of all this : we are not able to render images from S3 bucket from cache directory of /uploads/tmp with following error

ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/uploads/tmp/20150504-1320-12-1742/photo_e0c4783f745111d774b4cc200deb62ce.jpeg"):

when we hit the following URL

http://www.lumstic.com/uploads/tmp/20150504-1320-12-1742/photo_e0c4783f745111d774b4cc200deb62ce.jpeg

So I guess precompiled paths of S3 images are mismatching , resulting into routing error.

Is there any way to revert back to the - "day before yesterday's state of instance" of production located on Heroku (ashoka-survey-web) ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any way to revert back to the - "day before yesterday's state of instance" of production located on Heroku (ashoka-survey-web) ?

`heroku releases` will give you a list of releases you have pushed to heroku:

```
=== remote-wind Releases
v285  Rollback to v282                          kp@example.com      2014/12/24 12:02:53
v284  Detach HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_ROSE (@ref:bu..  kp@example.com      2014/12/24 12:01:25
v283  Deploy c393ad2                            mc@example.com    2014/12/18 10:01:39
v282  Update HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_ONYX by herok..  heroku-postgresql 2014/12/09 17:14:25
v281  Deploy 09b1f4c                            mc@example.com    2014/11/17 11:39:23
v280  Deploy 3f51a55                            mc@example.com    2014/10/10 12:38:38
v279  Deploy 1279d35                            mc@example.com    2014/10/10 11:59:25
v278  Rollback to v274                          mc@example.com    2014/10/09 17:06:35
v277  Rollback to v275                          mc@example.com    2014/10/09 17:03:26
```

You can then easily rollback to a release with `heroku rollback [version]`. Example `heroku rollback v238`. This rolls back the code to the target commit and also restores any env vars or settings which you have done on Heroku.

It does not however have any effect on the content of the databases attached to your app.